# Сделать подчёркивание ссылки за текстом

Tags: css

Друзья, привет!
Нужна помощь. Имею вот такой CSS:

```css
body {background: #ffda00;}
a {
    position: relative;
    color: #00a650; /*задаём цвет ссылки*/
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1; /*задаём высоту строки*/
    text-decoration: none; /*убираем подчёркивание*/
}
a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /*изменить на right:0;, чтобы изменить направление подчёркивания */
    width: 0;/*задаём длинну линии до наведения курсора*/
    height: 6px; /*задаём ширину линии*/
    background-color: #ffffff; /*задаём цвет линии*/
    content: "";
    transition: width 0.3s ease-out; /*задаём время анимации*/
    bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after {
    width: 100%; /*устанавливаем значение 100% чтобы ссылка подчёркивалась полностью*/
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Контакты</a>
```

При помощи него делаю нужное подчёркивание, однако оно перекрывает текст, т.к. располагается уровнем выше. Хочу сделать подчёркивание ссылок за текстом, т.е. уровнем ниже, чтобы текст оставался читаемым, а подчеркивание было под текстом. Прикрепляю картинку для наглядности. (если можете подсказать, посмотрев сайт, то реализовано нужное подчеркивание на unit*city (точка вместо *, а на сайте нажмите на гамбургер)

[image: нужно как справа]

Comment: Вроде бы простого `z-index: -1` достаточно для достижения желаемого

Comment: @andreymal, почти, но если только его добавить,вроде под фон уйти может.

Comment: @Qwertiy насколько я понимаю, position:relative у ссылки не даст этому случиться (впрочем, точно я не проверял). А если всё-таки уйдёт, то можно ссылке z-index:1 добавить или типа того

Comment: @andreymal, там есть варианты. В данном случае вроде работает.

Comment: Парни, гигантское спасибо вам! Отметил код, который сработал, как решение моего вопроса. Код, который предложили во втором отклике, когда нажимаешь на "выполнить код" на этом сайте тоже работает, однако на моем он не заработал...

Comment: @Sevastopol', не дубликат потому что в этом вопросе ещё анимация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

надо использовать `z-index`:

```css
body {
  background: #ffda00;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #00a650;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover:after, a:focus:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Контакты</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition:all .5s;
}

a:hover:before {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="Link куда-то"><span>Я ссылка</span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот на градиенте, без псевдо элементов:

```css
a {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, wheat 50%, #0000 51%);
  background-size: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 300ms;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.center {
  background-position: center;
}

.right {
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<a>LEFT</a><br>
<a class="center">CENTER</a><br>
<a class="right">RIGHT</a><br>
```

Comment: Ух ты, круто! Не знал, что так можно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy бэкграунд жеж, им можно один пиксель закрасить, со всеми вытекающими